# $f$ is continuous function from $ [0,1]$ to itself and f(0)=0, f(1)=1 and $f(f(x))=x$ then show that $f(x)=x$ on$[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, inverse-function

If $f$ is continuous from $ [0,1]$ to itself and $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$ and $f(f(x))=x$ then show that $f(x)=x$ for every $ x $ in the domain of function.

I'd like to prove this statement, my idea goes like below:

Suppose that the converse of the statement holds. then without loss of generality, assume that there exists some $c$ in $[0,1]$ such that $d=f(c)>c$. By symmetry, $f(d)=f(f(c))<f(c)=d$. And $f$ is bijective because $f$ has an inverse function in this domain. So $f$ should be strictly increasing function.
But on $[c,d]$, $f$ is decreasing.
This is a contradiction.

So it should be that $f(x)=x$ on $[0,1]$.

Is this argument right? And I'd like to know another argument which prove this statement. Thank you for your answer in advance :)

Comment: Looks ok to me.

Comment: @freakish thx indeed!

Comment: "Then without loss of generality, assume that there exists some $c$ in $[0,1]$ such that $d=f(c)>c.$" I am not quite sure why you do not lose generality by making that assumption. At best, you can make the proof with the assumption that $f(c)>c$ for som $c$ and then claim that it's the same when there is some $h$ such that $f(h)<h$. However, I don't see exactly where you are using the hypothesis $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$.

Comment: Also, the correct statement would be "But on $[c,d]$, $f$ is not monotone".

Comment: Note that the function $f$ is one one and continuous and by IVT it is clearly a bijection. Thus $f=f^{-1}$ and clearly a reflection with respect to line  $y=x$ shows that $f$ must be identity.

Comment: Since the condition $f(f(x))=x$ implies $f$ is $1-1$, together with the fact that $f$ is continuous, it follows that $f$ is monotonically increasing (since we are given $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1.$) WLOG if there exists some $c$ with $c<f(c),$ taking $f$ on both sides we get $f(c)<c,$ a contradiction.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I have pondered as Aryaman Jal did.

Answer (score 3):

It is definitely not o.k. If $f\ne{\rm id}$ then there is a $c$ with $f(c)=d\ne c$ and $f(d)=c$, and one of $c$ or $d$ is larger, say $d$. But this does not imply that $f$ is decreasing on $[c,d]$. Furthermore you seem to make use of the fact that a continuous bijective $f:\>[0,1]\to[0,1]$ has to be monotone. This is indeed true, and has been proven here many times, but it is not obvious.

Instead produce a clearcut inconsistent situation: If $f\ne{\rm id}$ then there is a $c>0$ with $f(c)=d>c$, and $f(d)=c$, by assumption. On the other hand $f(0)=0<c<d=f(c)$. Therefore there is a $d'\in\>]0,c[\>$ with $f(d')=c$, by the intermediate value theorem. We then would have $d'=f(c)=d$, contradicting $d'<c<d$.

Comment: thx:) As you said, I already knew that continuous bijective function is monotonic in closed interval. Thank you for pointig out, f is not necesseraily decreasing on $[c,d]$.

Answer (score 2):

Take $y \in [0, 1]$. Then there is some $x \in [0, 1]$ such that $f(x)=y$. Define $z_n:=f^n(x)$, where $f^1:=f$ and $f^{n+1}:=f \circ f^n$. Then $z_{2n}=x$ and $z_{2n+1}=y$. Since $f$ is increasing, $(z_n)$ is monotone(and bounded), hence convergent. So $x=y=f(x)$.

Comment: The function was not supposed to be differentiable.

Comment: I didn't suppose it.

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution(Not a solid proof, rather a thought):

$f(f(x))=x$ implies that $f$ is the inverse of itself i.e. its symmetrical about $y=x$.

And as it has a inverse it must be bijective i.e. **one-one** and onto.

As $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$ and it's continuous on $[0,1]$.

$y=x$, which is your proof